# SIGSEGV deep inside MediaPlayer since upgrade to Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, media-player, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, chromium

I developed a music app that was working well on Android pre-Ice Cream Sandwich. But since I upgraded to 4.0.3, I started getting random issues with the MediaPlayer that I never had before. For example, this is what I just got by calling mediaPlayer.reset while the instance was in playback completed state:

```
07-10 15:27:51.842: D/NuCachedSource2(13537): [setBreak]mForceBreak = 2  
07-10 15:27:51.842: I/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport(13537): initiateDisconnect start  
07-10 15:27:51.852: A/libc(13537): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1)  
07-10 15:27:52.362: I/DEBUG(13536): debuggerd: 2012-07-10 15:27:52  
07-10 15:27:52.362: I/DEBUG(13536): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***  
07-10 15:27:52.362: I/DEBUG(13536): Build fingerprint: 'tmous/htc_ruby/ruby:4.0.3/IML74K/373265.3:user/release-keys'  
07-10 15:27:52.362: I/DEBUG(13536): pid: 13537, tid: 13537  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<  
07-10 15:27:52.362: I/DEBUG(13536): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000010  
[...]  
07-10 15:27:52.402: I/DEBUG(13536):  scr 60000010  
07-10 15:27:52.542: I/DEBUG(13536):          #00  pc 00000010    
07-10 15:27:52.542: I/DEBUG(13536):          #01  pc 0010f70e  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (_ZNK3net11BoundNetLog8AddEntryENS_6NetLog9EventTypeENS1_10EventPhaseERK13scoped_refptrINS1_15EventParametersEE)  
07-10 15:27:52.542: I/DEBUG(13536):          #02  pc 0010f71a  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (_ZNK3net11BoundNetLog8EndEventENS_6NetLog9EventTypeERK13scoped_refptrINS1_15EventParametersEE)  
07-10 15:27:52.542: I/DEBUG(13536):          #03  pc 001a4458  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (_ZN3net10URLRequest11set_contextEPNS_17URLRequestContextE)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #04  pc 0012467e  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android10SfDelegate18initiateDisconnectEv)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #05  pc 00121ca6  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android22ChromiumHTTPDataSource12disconnect_lEv)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #06  pc 00121d04  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android22ChromiumHTTPDataSource10disconnectEv)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #07  pc 00121776  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android22ChromiumHTTPDataSource12breakNetworkEv)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #08  pc 00083b38  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android13AwesomePlayer12breakNetworkENS_18FORCE_BREAK_STATUSE)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #09  pc 00086c9e  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android13AwesomePlayer5resetEv)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #10  pc 00027e5e  /system/lib/libmediaplayerservice.so (_ZN7android17StagefrightPlayer5resetEv)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #11  pc 0002304a  /system/lib/libmediaplayerservice.so (_ZN7android18MediaPlayerService6Client5resetEv)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #12  pc 00041734  /system/lib/libmedia.so (_ZN7android13BnMediaPlayer10onTransactEjRKNS_6ParcelEPS1_j)
```

And a short while after that:

```
07-10 15:27:55.645: W/AudioSystem(236): AudioFlinger server died!  
07-10 15:27:55.645: W/AudioSystem(236): AudioPolicyService server died!  
07-10 15:27:55.645: W/AudioSystem(13123): AudioFlinger server died!  
07-10 15:27:55.645: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(13123): media server died  
07-10 15:27:55.645: E/MediaPlayer(13123): error (100, 0)  
07-10 15:27:55.645: E/MediaPlayer(13123): error (100, 0)  
07-10 15:27:55.645: I/ServiceManager(116): service 'media.audio_flinger' died  
07-10 15:27:55.645: I/ServiceManager(116): service 'media.player' died  
07-10 15:27:55.645: I/ServiceManager(116): service 'media.camera' died  
07-10 15:27:55.645: I/ServiceManager(116): service 'media.audio_policy' died  
07-10 15:27:55.645: I/DEBUG(13536): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!  
07-10 15:27:55.665: I/DEBUG(13617): debuggerd: May  2 2012 21:31:04
```

Does someone have a hint about what can cause a segmentation fault at this level?

Thanks.

EDIT : After further investiguating, I discovered some simple steps to reproduce the segmentation fault on a HTC Ruby (HTC Amaze 4G) running Android 4.0.3:

Using 2 MediaPlayer instances:

1. Start playback of some remote audio file using first instance;
2. While first instance is still playing, start playback of another remote audio file using second instance;
3. When first instance has completed playback, call reset on it. This is fine.
4. When second instance has completed playback, call reset() on it. Unexpectedly, this causes a SIGSEGV inside Chromium, which causes a Media Server Died error to be dispatched to all instances.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logcat there,

```
07-10 15:27:52.542: I/DEBUG(13536):          #00  pc 00000010    
07-10 15:27:52.542: I/DEBUG(13536):          #01  pc 0010f70e  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (_ZNK3net11BoundNetLog8AddEntryENS_6NetLog9EventTypeENS1_10EventPhaseERK13scoped_refptrINS1_15EventParametersEE)  
07-10 15:27:52.542: I/DEBUG(13536):          #02  pc 0010f71a  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (_ZNK3net11BoundNetLog8EndEventENS_6NetLog9EventTypeERK13scoped_refptrINS1_15EventParametersEE)  
07-10 15:27:52.542: I/DEBUG(13536):          #03  pc 001a4458  /system/lib/libchromium_net.so (_ZN3net10URLRequest11set_contextEPNS_17URLRequestContextE)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #04  pc 0012467e  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android10SfDelegate18initiateDisconnectEv)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #05  pc 00121ca6  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android22ChromiumHTTPDataSource12disconnect_lEv)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #06  pc 00121d04  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android22ChromiumHTTPDataSource10disconnectEv)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #07  pc 00121776  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android22ChromiumHTTPDataSource12breakNetworkEv)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #08  pc 00083b38  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android13AwesomePlayer12breakNetworkENS_18FORCE_BREAK_STATUSE)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #09  pc 00086c9e  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android13AwesomePlayer5resetEv)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #10  pc 00027e5e  /system/lib/libmediaplayerservice.so (_ZN7android17StagefrightPlayer5resetEv)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #11  pc 0002304a  /system/lib/libmediaplayerservice.so (_ZN7android18MediaPlayerService6Client5resetEv)  
07-10 15:27:52.552: I/DEBUG(13536):          #12  pc 00041734  /system/lib/libmedia.so (_ZN7android13BnMediaPlayer10onTransactEjRKNS_6ParcelEPS1_j)
```

Those lines are pin-pointing the source of the trace, its `libchromium` that is faulting somewhere, and yes, the names of the symbols used looks obscure but it is mangled C++ names that were linked in at build-time of the ROM.

You read the trace from the bottom up. And that's the clue, usually the topmost at `#00/pc....` or `#01/pc....` as illustrated above, is the pinpoint of failure.

Might be worthy to check with your manufacturer to see if there's an update available or check their HTC forum to find out if that has been resolved?

Comment: My question wasn't clear enough. I am the developer of the app, but the thing is I cannot debug Chromium: I'm stuck at MediaPlayer level, which has been working fine so far all devices and all OS, but not so much on a HTC Ruby running on Ice Cream Sandwich. I did more testing and the problem seems to appear only when the app uses two MediaPlayer instances in order to cross-fade tunes. The segmentation fault occurs when the obsolete instance is reset while the other instance plays (although it works sometimes).

Comment: Yes, your question was not exactly clear! And you cannot debug chromium as I have said in the answer, its built with debugging stripped out of it at build-time of the ICS ROM....

Comment: The executable may be stripped, but you have the approximate source code in AOSP and non-strippable dynamic link symbols as a guide.  It would be easier with the latest objdump out of AOSP master which now decodes the plt entries on arm.   But unless the device is rooted, it's going to be hard to make any fixes.

Comment: In the meantime, since it seems to only happen with HTC Amaze 4G running Android 4.0.3, I've submitted a bug report here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34723  I hope it's the right place.

Comment: I think more than one instance of MediaPlayer can still be used to play sounds, otherwise it would be a major downgrade from previous releases of Android. But since each MediaPlayer instance consumes valuable system resources, we must keep the number of instances as low as possible. Using two instances seems reasonable, even if they compete for hardware. When the crash occurs, there's only one instance left in use (the other one has been reset or released after it has completed playback).